# Why is the folder name "bin" used in some frameworks and languages?

Tags: java, terminology

I have been learning Java. And still after a prolonged time I don't know **why the name of the folder is "bin"** where one find all the tools for java?

Is there is any logical reason behind that?

I have also noticed the same in .Net framework also.

Comment: `bin` is short for `binary`. It's the location of binary (or executable) files.

Comment: `bin` as an abbreviation for `binaries` existed long before Java or .NET.

Comment: `bin` is where you put trash. JOKE! JOKE! JOKE!  Our local waste paper bins used to have `/usr/local/bin` printed on them. I miss those days.

Comment: Reading a question like this sometimes makes me feel rather long in the tooth. I need to [remind myself of this](http://xkcd.com/1053/) constantly

Comment: hmm, that makes me young (or ignorant (or ignorant and young)) ... I had always assumed it was bin as in container, ex: trash bin... >_>

Answer (score 42):

`bin` is short for binary. It generally refers to the built applications (also know as binaries) that do something for a specific system.

To quote from [ChrisF's answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224606/bin-directory-and-path):

> You usually put all the binary files for a program in the bin directory. This would be the executable itself and any dlls (dynamic link libraries) that the program uses.

Answer (score 25):

`bin` is a standard directory name in typical [UNIX/UNIX-like systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_directory_structure).  It goes back to the early days of UNIX. `/bin`, `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` are directories where executable binaries are stored on most UNIX or UNIX-like systems.  Java simply used this conventional name to designate where executables are stored within the Java home directory.

Comment: What did Multics do? Was it a convention that predated Unix, or was it something that the original Unix hackers invented?

Answer (score 1):

As you know every language finally converted into machine code, I mean the code which a machine can understand and machine only understand either 0 or 1 (you also can say either on or off).this 0 and 1 form of data representation is called binary data representation. Hence every language create binary code so that machine can understand and process it.so the folder where all these machine code reside is called as bin(binary).